# How to determine which DNS resolved a request

Tags: dns, dhcp

How can I verify that my client system is using the primary DNS vs. failing over to the secondary DNS?  I've found lots of information about verifying the configuration that the clients receive, but not how to determine whether the client is using the primary or secondary.

My immediate interest is to determine whether OS X is using the primary, but I also would like to determine when Windows 10 is using primary or failing over to secondary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the **Server** line on any of these replies.

**On Windows**:

```
   > nslookup 192.168.101.39
   Server: dns1.local
   Address: 192.168.101.24

   Name: enigma.local
   Address: 192.168.101.39
```

**On Mac or Linux**

```
  > dig hague

    ; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> hague
    ;; global options: +cmd
    ;; Got answer:
    ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 61729
    ;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0

    ;; QUESTION SECTION:
    ;hague.                         IN      A

    ;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
    .                       10800   IN      SOA     a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2015092100 1800 900 604800 86400

    ;; Query time: 45 msec
    ;; SERVER: 192.168.11.1#53(192.168.11.1)
    ;; WHEN: Mon Sep 21 17:56:43 2015
    ;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 98
```

Comment: curious reference to hague, browsers warn that it is a malware site

Comment: LOL, I did not know that. It is my Arch Linux machine, it stands for `Rasalhague`, a star in Ophiucus and one of my dogs.

Comment: np, I'll just download and install whatever it tells me to

Comment: If I understand dig docs, that is answering my question and reporting that my secondary is being used as suspected and not primary.  That's frustrating and now more to solve, but thank you for the tip!

Comment: @MichaelPrescott I did not mean that the site reported as malware source is mine **at all**; I only meant my pc is **local**, and it happens to have the same name, but it is not the infamous site. In fact, that pc does not even host a Web server!

Comment: understood, not a problem. To anyone else following the comments, I was joking, no one should download and install software from a malware site :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are in a Windows environment;

If so then load Command Prompt on your client and type nslookup. This will show you the default DNS Server and its IP.

You can then type the hostname of another machine on the network to see where the response comes from.

Comment: Sorry, I'll update the question.  I actually would like to verify on several platforms, but immediately I'm on OS X.   I've found lots of information about how to verify the configuration, but no information about how to actually verify the primary DNS resolved the request.